# MySQL query works with POST but not with GET (Node/Express)

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

POST works but GET doesn't work.

This works:

```
app.post('/POSTexample', function(req, res) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?', req.session.username, function(error, results, fields) {
            #using query results
            response.redirect('/account');
        });
    res.redirect('/account');
});
```

But this doesn't work (gets stuck and never loads):

```
app.get('/GETexample', function(req, res) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?', req.session.username, function(error, results, fields) {
                #using query results
        });
    res.redirect('/account');
});
```

What are the possible solutions to this issue?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Also isn't your `if` statement backwards? You are selecting `req.session.username` but only if there is no login.

Comment: @JasonRoman By "doesn't work", I mean it gets stuck and never loads (GET never returned the results from MySQL, I've tried about ten times). Moreover, I only took a part of the code (because that's where the problem is); I should've removed the ```if``` part. Sorry about that! I'll remove it rightaway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `res.redirect()` calls *in the callback function* from your MySql queries. The way you have it, you're redirecting before the queries complete.

asynchronous coding takes some getting used to, doesn't it?